# Can I use JS or jQuery to test if SVG images are supported?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, mobile, svg

I am using an SVG logo on a website, and in most browsers it is working fine. However, on some IE versions and on mobile browsers, the image shows up as a failed image box. Is there any way I could use JS or some library (preferably jQuery) to check for SVG compatibility with the least amount of false negatives, and simply switch to a .png version of the image?

The site is this: http://zero31b.x10.mx/samote, and the SVG images are the little blue globe things

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3202087 is one way. (It does require JavaScript, though.) I found it by looking up "svg with png fallback".

Comment: At work we successfully utilize modernizr - http://modernizr.com/ for this.

Comment: By the way, have you noticed your SVG is 30 kB?

Answer (score 0):

Tavmjong Bah wrote the comprehensive article on SVG and PNG fallback:

http://tavmjong.free.fr/SVG/BUTTON_TEST/button_test.html

The simplest code he/she gives is

```
    <img src="buttonA.svg" alt="A sample SVG button." 
       onerror="this.removeAttribute('onerror'); this.src='buttonA.png'"/>
```

But if you have more features you have to test for you might
consider the modernizr version.

To create the png-Version of you SVG-Button madrobby on github recommended
using **librsvg-convert**

Comment: Is the link around the image actually neccessary?